# Cant send email from Laravel with gmail, TSL problem

Tags: php, laravel-5

[image]

(1/1) Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "tsl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #6]

This is the exact message poping up.
Why am I getting this. Ive tried a LOT of suggestions from stackoverflow and other sites, but cant get it to work.

**.ENV**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=***********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl
MAIL_NAME='Mela Solutions'
```

**mail.php**

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'name' => env('MAIL_NAME')],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tsl'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear - I think you've fat-fingered `tls` as `tsl` :-)

Comment: Okay, ive changed it and even though I hoped it would be it, it still giving me the same error. I added **php artisan config:cache** for good measure

Comment: Did you activate the 2-Step Verification on gmail?

Comment: If you are getting the same error then it seems you must still have `tsl` somewhere?  I think `config:cache` does actually also *clear* config first, but why complicate things, caching is not what you need now, try `config:clear`.

Comment: I think you can try with `Mail_Encryption=ssl` in `.env` file